# How to set the background of webview transparent in winRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a web view which loads html content in a page.How its back ground can set to transparent.I set the html background transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge that's not possible since this an actual HTML page you are rendering inside the Webview. 
The webview does not derive from [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.aspx) and because of this, it does not support the same templating possibilities as if you we using a control that derived from [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.aspx).
Also since browsers can't have a transparent website, the website will appear white per default.

This may not directly relate to your question however I think it's still important to know when using the Webview. There is some important remarks from the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) concerning UI and rendering:

> WebView has the characteristic that other UI regions such as controls cannot be rendered on top of the WebView. This is because of how window regions are handled internally, particularly how input events are processed and how the screen draws. If you want to render HTML content and also place other UI elements on top of that HTML content, you should use WebViewBrush as the render area. The WebView still provides the HTML source information, and you reference that WebView through the SourceName property. WebViewBrush does not have this overlay limitation.
>   If you want to display an interactive WebView that only occasionally has overlapping content (such as a drop-down list or app bar), you can temporarily hide the WebView control when necessary, replacing it with an element using a WebViewBrush fill. Then, when the overlapping content is no longer present, you can display the original WebView again. For more info, see the WebView control sample.

For more information see the [full documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<WebView DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: This will give you a black background, instead of transparent. Android used to have same problem, but it was fixed with 4.1. Hopefully it will be fixed with WinRT ... eventually.

Comment: This works, gives a transparent background to the contents of WebView (I used it in code-behind, not in XAML).

Answer (score 2):

They have fixed it in Windows Universal App.
If you set DefaultBackgroundColor to Transparent 
and

`body, html {
background:transparent;
}`

you will get what you want